# Oozie run shell scripts on random nodes

Tags: shell, hadoop, ftp, hdfs, oozie

I wrote smth like custom oozie FTP action (simple example described in "Professional Hadoop Solutions By: Boris Lublinsky; Kevin T. Smith; Alexey Yakubovich"). We have HDFS on node1 and Oozie server on node2. Node2 also has HDFS client.

My problem:

1. Oozie job started from node1 (All needed files located on HDFS on node1).
2. Oozie custom FTP action successfully downloaded CSV files from FTP on node2 (oozie server located)
3. I should pass file into HDFS and create external table from CSV on node1.
   I tried to use Java action and call `fileSystem.moveFromLocalFile(...)` method. Also I tried to use Shell action like `/usr/bin/hadoop fs -moveFromLocal /tmp\import_folder/filename.csv /user/user_for_import/imported/filename.csv` but I hadn't effect. All actions seems tried to look files on node1. The same result if I start oozie job from node2.

Question: can I set node for FTP action to load files from FTP on node1? Or can I have any other ways to pass downloaded files in HDFS instead described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oozie runs all its actions as MR jobs on nodes from a configured Map Reduce cluster. There is no way to make Oozie run some actions on a particular node.

Basically, you should use Flume to ingest files into HDFS. Set up a Flume agent on your FTP node.

Answer (score 0):

Ozzie allows user to run a shell script on a particular node via oozie sssh shell extension.
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SshActionExtension.html